# ArrayList of ArrayList in Java with SQLite consult

Tags: java, sqlite

Is there a more efficent or standard way to get data from a database?
This way is comfortable but maybe it's not the most efficient

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getUsers() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> res;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM User";
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, propierties)){
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    res = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String id = rs.getString("id_user");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    res.add(id);
                    res.add(name);
                    result.add(res);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: why not creating a Object that hold id and name and other information and use it to fill your data??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a clss User

```
public class User{
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Stringid) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` you can use `ArrayList<User>`

```
ArrayList<User> result = new ArrayList<>();
User user;
...
while (rs.next()) {
    user = new User(rs.getString("id_user"), rs.getString("name"));
    result.add(user);
}
```

Note for best practice `id` don't use String type, instead use Integer, Long, ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a List of Lists, it may be useful to create a `Map`, specifically in this case a `HashMap`. I've set the return type to be a generic `Map` object in case sometime in the future you want to change from a `HashMap`, you won't have to remember to change the return type.

```
// Returns IDs that map to name Strings
public Map<String, String> getUsers() throws SQLException {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM User";
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)){
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("id_user");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    result.put(id, name);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You will notice that other answers create a `User` class that holds the data. I would suggest doing this if you have other fields in your database table that you will also retrieve and want access to in your program. If all you are concerned with is the 'user_id' and 'name', it is more efficient to just have a map like I've described below so you don't increase your application's memory footprint. (Of course having a `User` object would be better OO design, so you might like that approach better).

Change the function to be like so:

```
// Returns IDs that map to Users
public Map<String, User> getUsers() throws SQLException {
        Map<String, User> result = new HashMap<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM User";
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)){
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("id_user");
                    String name = rs.getString("name");
                    result.put(id, new User(id, name);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```